# GNU linker get objects through INPUT

Tags: linker

I want to use the suggestion made in de GNU linker manual page 40, i.e. INPUT (subr.o), thus specifying object members in a script file.
Eventually I want to specify all the object members of my program that the linker has to use.

The script file looks like this (only the files parts is shown)

```
SEARCH_DIR(../lib)

STARTUP(boot.o)
ENTRY(_start)   

GROUP (libkernel.a libkflib.a)

INPUT (
    lowcore.o
    init.o
    kfalloc.o
    kflog.o
    kfprintf.o
)
```

The linker replies with:

```
attempt to open boot.o failed
attempt to open ../lib/boot.o failed
m68k-rtems4.11-ld: cannot find boot.o
```

I have specified the search path, the libraries and a list of object members; the object members are definitly in the libraries.
I was expection the linker to look for object members in the working directory and if not there using the search path and libraries.
Obviously there is something wrong but I cannot figure it out.

Suggestions are welcome in order to achieve the desired way of linking: specifying all objects to link an not more than that.

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misread [the manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/ld/File-Commands.html#File-Commands):

> INPUT(file file ...)
>
> The INPUT command directs the linker to include the named files in the link,
>     as though they were named on the command line.
>
> ...
>
> In case a sysroot prefix is configured, and the filename starts with the / character,
>     and the script being processed was located inside the sysroot prefix, the 
>     filename will be looked for in the sysroot prefix. Otherwise, the linker will
>     try to open the file in the current directory. If it is not found, the linker
>     will search through the archive library search path. See the description of 
>     -L in Command Line Options.
>
> If you use INPUT (-lfile), ld will transform the name to libfile.a, as with 
>     the command line argument -l.
>
> ...
>
> GROUP(file file ...)
>
> The GROUP command is like INPUT, except that the named files should all be 
>      archives, and they are searched repeatedly until no new undefined references
>      are created.
>
> STARTUP(filename)
>
> The STARTUP command is just like the INPUT command, except that filename will
>      become the first input file to be linked, as though it were specified first on the command line

Or perhaps you have read some other documentation that is in error.

You have got wrong the impression that command `GROUP(libboo.a...)` is complementary to `INPUT(foo.o...)`
and `STARTUP(bar.o)`, with the effect that files `bar.o, foo.o...` will be searched for in archives
`libboo.a...` and - if found - will be extracted from the archives and added to the linkage.

`INPUT(foo.o)` has the same effect as specifying `foo.o` on the linker
commandline except that if not found in the current directory it will be searched
for in the same way that a static library specified with the `-l` option would be, with any `SEARCH_DIR(path)`
commands in the linker script having the same influence as commandline options
`-Lpath`.

`STARTUP(bar.o)` has the same effect as specifying `bar.o` *first* in the linker
commandline.

`GROUP(libboo.a...)` has the same effect as the commandline options

```
--start-group -lboo.a... --end-group
```

again with any `SEARCH_DIR(path)` commands actiing like `-Lpath`.

`INPUT(foo.o)` and `STARTUP(bar.o)` are unconnected with `GROUP(libboo.a...)`, just as in the commandline options:

```
bar.o --start-group -lboo.a... --end-group foo.o
```

`bar.o` and `foo.o` are an input files unconnected with `--start-group -lboo.a... --end-group`.

The linker never looks inside static libraries for an input object file that it otherwise
fails to find.

So this command:

```
INPUT (
    lowcore.o
    init.o
    kfalloc.o
    kflog.o
    kfprintf.o
)
```

in your linker script requires the linker to find those object files in the current 
directory or in `../lib`, and they are not there. Similarly for `STARTUP(boot.o)`. Hence
the linkage errors.

Those object files aren't there, but static libraries `libkernel.a` and `libkflib.a` *are*,
and you tell us they contain all all those object files as members. In that case
you simply don't need:

```
INPUT (
    lowcore.o
    init.o
    kfalloc.o
    kflog.o
    kfprintf.o
)
```

because the linker will search static libraries to find object files that
provide definitions of any symbols for which definitions are called for
by references within object files that it has already linked. You don't have to
tell it to.

But to give the linker any reason to search a static library at all you
must have told it to link *some* object file that refers to some undefined symbol(s)
before it considers the static library.

That's the reason why, on the commandline, you must place object files before the
libraries to which they refer and it is why, in a self-contained linker script, if you
add libraries to the linkage with `GROUP(libboo.a...)` or with `INPUT (-lboo...)`,
you must also specify an object file to be linked *first*, with a `STARTUP`
command.

So while your failing `INPUT` command is unnecessary and can just be
deleted, your failing `STARTUP(boot.o)` must remain, to initiate
any linkage. And must not fail.

To make `STARTUP(boot.o)` succeed, you have to put the object file `boot.o`
*itself* in a place where the script will tell the linker to look for it,
either the current directory or `../lib`. Presumably, the current directory.

And when you do that, it becomes pointless to have `boot.o` remain as a member
of one your static libraries, since it can't be linked from within one. Best
delete it from whichever libary you have it in. Leaving it there is similar
to putting the `main` function of a program into one of the libraries you
will link it with.

Comment: The linker behave as explained and thus as specified; now I will solve this outside the linker script. Something like making all the object members available in the working directory prior to call the linker.

Comment: @BenJ Hi. That would be a straightforward way to go. You may want to see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)